# Get count of object from list?

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Agenda 
{

public string StartDate;

public string EndDate;

public string Id;

}

public Class Appointments

{

public Agenda agenda;
```

}

```
public class ViewModel
```

{

```
List<Appointments> collection = new List<Appointments>();    

collection.Add(new Agenda { StartDate = "date1" , EndDate = "date1", Id= "1234567" } );

collection.Add(new Agenda { StartDate = "date2" , EndDate = "date2", Id= "1234567" } );

collection.Add(new Agenda { StartDate = "date3" , EndDate = "date3", Id= "2222222" } );

collection.Add(new Agenda { StartDate = "date4" , EndDate = "date4", Id= "3333333" } );

collection.Add(new Agenda { StartDate = "date5" , EndDate = "date5", Id= "3333333" } );

collection.Add(new Agenda { StartDate = "date1" , EndDate = "date1", Id= "3333333" } );

collection.Add(new Agenda { StartDate = "date1" , EndDate = "date1", Id= "1234567" } );

}
```

I want Linq solution to get the number of **Agendas** from the **Viewmodel** **Appointement** property

eg. Id = "1234567" has 3 Agenda object in List

```
Id = "3333333" has 3 Agenda object in List

Id = "2222222" has 2 Agenda object in List












enter code here
```

Comment: you cannot add Agenda objects to a collection of Appointment and your View model needs a method or a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var groups = collection.GroupBy(x => x.Id);
foreach(var group in groups) {
    Console.WriteLine("Count for Id {0}: {1}", group.Key, group.Count());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`(from a in ViewModel.collection where a.Id.Equals("1234567") select a).Count();`